# Change GRAVITY and SIZE of View programmatically

Tags: android, layout, view, resize, size

I would like to change the size of my View (CanvasView extends View) programmatically maintaining gravity. My View is inside RelativeLayout. I tried many different approaches but I am stuck...

The point is, that I would like to set size depending on screen size:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ToolsAndConstants.metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        windowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(ToolsAndConstants.metrics);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary);

        CanvasView canvasView = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_CanvasView);
        canvasView.canvasWidth  = (ToolsAndConstants.metrics.widthPixels / 10 * 7) - 10;
        canvasView.canvasHeight = (ToolsAndConstants.metrics.heightPixels / 10 * 4) - 10; 
        canvasView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(canvasView.canvasWidth, canvasView.canvasHeight));

    (...)
    }
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_dictionary_relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gray_patterns_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LogReader" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_dictionary_linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/activity_dictionary_progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_dictionary_textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Loading dictionary..."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_dictionary_frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <view
            android:id="@+id/activity_dictionary_CanvasView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            class="com.example.dictionary.CanvasView"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**How can I resize it?**

Comment: What is the issue?  You probably don't need to add params to the fl.  If you are trying to set the location of the view in the rl then use      view.setX(number); and view.setY(number);.  That will set them and then use  view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(Width,Height)); to set the size of the view.

Comment: When do you call requestLayout on your view after the measure and layout pass? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Layout

Comment: The problem is, that when I don't change the size inside the program, my View is visible in the bottom of screen, centered horizontally. What I want is to have it i the bottom centered horizontally, but bigger. But when I change its size, it appears in the top left corner of Relative Layout...Is there something like             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" that I could write in the code_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
canvasView = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.activity_dictionary_CanvasView);
canvasView.canvasWidth  = 100;
canvasView.canvasHeight = 100;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
         new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(canvasView.canvasWidth, canvasView.canvasHeight);
//I want my Canvas be above LinearLayout and Horizontaly centered
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.activity_dictionary_linearLayout2);
canvasView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```